# What is the best approach to handle exceptions in WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service deployed on two or more remote machines and there is a desktop based application that is used by the client to access any wcf service.

**The WCF service is connected to SQL server 2005 to read and write data.**
This is an intranet scenario in which the client should be on same domain.

Now there can be scenarios where the wcf service throws exceptions:

1. Invalid URL
2. WCF service is down
3. SQL server 2005 is not running
4. Client is not on the same domain
5. Authentication fails
6. Authorization fails

and many other exceptions.

For every exception I have to perform some action or update a status bar, depending on the exception. For example if authorization fails I have to prompt the user to re-enter their credentials.

Please suggest the best design approach to handle this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can definitely catch and handle all exceptions that happen on your service class and turn them into a FaultException or FaultException exception.

That way, you won't "fault" (or tear down) the communications channel between your client and server.

Even better approach would be to implement the `IErrorHandler` interface on your service class that provides a way to globally catch all exceptions as they happen and provide a FaultException instead, that's SOAP compliant.

You can even turn your `IErrorHandler` into a configurable behavior that can be turned on or off in config.

See these articles and blog posts for more details:

- [Rory Primrose: Implementing IErrorHandler](http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler/)
- [Useful WCF behaviors: IErrorHandler](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626051037/http://www.steverb.com/post/2008/11/24/Useful-WCF-Behaviors-IErrorHandler.aspx)

Comment: I don't know much on IErrorHandler but I read articles and posts on using IErrorHandler it says it has some disadvantages. In some cases exception may directly be thrown from the wcf service to the client. Would you recommend me for IErrorHandler ??

Comment: Yes, by all means - I would **always** recommend using IErrorHandler. Can you post the links to these articles that say it has disadvantages?? Never heard of those - I'd like to investigate....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265551/wcf-errorhandler
Read the second post!! I don't know wheather it's correct or not but it always creates the confustion in my mind

Comment: Well, I guess he's expecting too much - IErrorHandler will catch all exceptions that occur ON THE SERVER - a communications error, or a mismatch in security settings, does not happen on the server - but before the message even reaches the server. This is a different scenario.

Comment: May I point you straight to Rory Primrose's post.  It's a complete working example.

Comment: @marc_s I realize this is a very old thread, but I'm running into the exact same issue (SecurityExceptions not caught by IErrorHandler). You say it does not happen on the server which is confusing me. The ServiceCredentials behavior is attached in the service host and does execute on the server (my WCF tracing captures the exception just fine). Is there a way to capture these exceptions?

Comment: How can I efficiently handle errors an exceptions of any type in the client side only (I am only the consumer, the server code is beyond me). Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33734660/75500) question I posted.

Comment: @marc_s, When I am calling my WCF Service from jquery ajax method, I always get error response in plain html format. When I parse the response using $.parseJSON() method, Invalid json format error is coming. How can I receive my error response in json format from WCF service?

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a custom fault class that is marked with the [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute
2. Mark the *method* on the service contract interface with [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx). Ie. `[FaultContract(typeof(CustomFault))]`
3. In your service method, catch any applicable internal exceptions and throw a [FaultException<CustomFault>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx). Alternatively, as marc_s mentioned, you can use IErrorHandler to map the exception to the fault.

Personally, I create a base Fault class that has a Reason property and I extend all custom faults from this class. When I want to throw the fault, I call:

```
throw Fault.Create<CustomFault>(new CustomFault("Boo hoo"));
```

It's also worth noting that I version my fault classes (including the common Fault class) along with all my other services. This is only a concern if service versioning is a concern, though.

Here's the basic Fault class (I've removed argument validation for brevity):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = XmlVersionNamespace.FaultNamespace)]
public abstract class Fault
{
    internal FaultReason Reason { get; set; }

    protected Fault(string reasonText)
    {
        Reason = new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText(reasonText, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Reason.ToString();
    }

    internal static FaultException<TDetail> Create<TDetail>(TDetail fault) where TDetail : Fault
    {
        return new FaultException<TDetail>(fault, fault.Reason);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard ! Can you please give me an example if suppose authentication fails. Just give me the class relation ships and how you will handle on client app..

Comment: I would create an AuthenticationFailedFault (extend it from Fault), passing a message to the base Fault constructor. In your client app, you just catch FaultException<AuthenticationFailedFault>, since AuthenticationFailedFault will be part of the WSDL (as long as you marked the method with [FaultContract])

Answer (score 2):

You can design the specific Fault Data Contracts for each of the exception scenario in your WCF service so that you can handle the fault/exception at client side respectively.

Comment: I am new to it can you please give me some link

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
  // Actions
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Log the exception
  // Throw Fault Exception back to client
  FaultException fe = new FaultException(ex.Message, new FaultCode("Your fault code"));
  //throw fault exception back to WCF client
  throw fe;
}
```