# Handling exceptions in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, soapexception

I have project in which i am calling soap based service . I am using fault and communication exception as mostly two of these exception occurs in calling of api. but what if any other exception occurs instead of these two exception in soap api ?

```
    try
    {
      //soap api
    }
    catch(FaultException ex)
    {
    }
    catch(CommunicationException ex)
    {
    }
```

Later on i read on internet about soap exception class. and i am considering to change my code like :

```
     try
    {
      //soap api
    }

    catch(SoapException ex)
    {
    }
```

Now what i need to know is if i use Soap Exception instead of fault and communication exception . would it be good ? all i need is the catch the exception if it occurs in soap api. however i want to know does the soap api also handles the fault and communication exception or i have to explicitly define my code like ?

```
 try
    {
      //soap api
    }
    catch(FaultException ex)
    {
    }
    catch(CommunicationException ex)
    {
    }
    catch(SoapException ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never see a `SoapException`. That's part of the obsolete ASMX technology.

See [Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx).

Comment: you mean to say is soap exception obselete now ? if yes dn what the best approach to achieve my task ?

Comment: I'm saying you will never see one if you stick to using WCF. The article where you read about `SoapException` was discussing an obsolete technology.

Comment: so what is the new one ? hope cause of you i could move my project to the latest technology ?

Answer (score 4):

As [stated on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715.aspx):

> The errors encountered by a WCF application belong to one of three
>   groups:
>
> - Communication Errors
> - Proxy/Channel Errors
> - Application Errors
>
> **Communication errors** occur when a network is unavailable, a client uses an incorrect address, or the service host is not listening for
>   incoming messages. Errors of this type are returned to the client as
>   CommunicationException or CommunicationException-derived classes.
>
> **Proxy/Channel errors** are errors that occur within the channel or proxy itself. Errors of this type include: attempting to use a proxy
>   or channel that has been closed, a contract mismatch exists between
>   the client and service, or the client’s credentials are rejected by
>   the service. There are many different types of errors in this
>   category, too many to list here. Errors of this type are returned to
>   the client as-is (no transformation is performed on the exception
>   objects).
>
> **Application errors** occur during the execution of a service operation. Errors of this kind are sent to the client as
>   `FaultException` or `FaultException<TDetail>`.
>
> Error handling in WCF is performed by one or more of the following:
>
> - Directly handling the exception thrown. This is only done for    communication and proxy/channel errors.
> - Using fault contracts
> - Implementing the IErrorHandler interface
> - Handling ServiceHost events
>
> **Fault Contracts** Fault contracts allow you to define the errors that can occur during service operation in a platform independent way.
>   By default all exceptions thrown from within a service operation will
>   be returned to the client as a FaultException object. The
>   FaultException object will contain very little information. You can
>   control the information sent to the client by defining a fault
>   contract and returning the error as a FaultException. For more
>   information, see Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and
>   Services.
>
> **IErrorHandler** The IErrorHandler interface allows you more control over how your WCF application responds to errors. It gives you full
>   control over the fault message that is returned to the client and
>   allows you to perform custom error processing such as logging. For
>   more information, see IErrorHandler and Extending Control Over Error
>   Handling and Reporting
>
> **ServiceHost Events** The ServiceHost class hosts services and defines several events that may be needed for handling errors. For
>   example:
>
> 1.Faulted
>
> 2.UnknownMessageReceived

You can also refer to a similar question, which has many good answers as well:
[What is the best approach to handle exceptions in WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536087/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-exceptions-in-wcf-service)

Comment: When you copy text, you must also quote everything that was copied. You can't just place a link at the bottom of the text, because that gives the impression that you authored it. Quotations must be explicit, as I've edited into the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the timeline to create a nice set of custom Exceptions extending from `ClientSafeException` then I would divide those up between client friendly exceptions and non-client friendly exceptions.

```
catch (ClientSafeException safeException)
{
    response.ServiceResponse= ExceptionHandler.ProcessSafeExceptionResponse(safeException);
     request.Succeeded = false;
}
catch (Exception unsafeException)
{
    response.ServiceResponse= ExceptionHandler.ProcessUnsafeExceptionResponse(unsafeException);
    request.Succeeded = false;
}
LogServiceResponse(request, response.ServiceResponse);

return response;
```

Sorry to not mention that the static `ExceptionHandler` class routes safe vs. non-safe client exceptions.